# Nix package requires `sudo` to access USB device

Tags: permissions, usb, sudo, nix

I wrote a Nix package to install the [libmonome](https://github.com/monome/libmonome) software for manipulating a [monome](https://monome.org/), which connects to the computer via USB. [My `libmonome` Nix package](https://github.com/JeffreyBenjaminBrown/nixos-experiments/blob/9e1b793b12166be1bc5bb5b058ffa17190acb23b/custom-packages/libmonome/default.nix) (that's a permanent link to the current unsatisfactory version) cannot access the device unless I use `sudo`:

```
[jeff@jbb-dell:~]$ monomeserial
libmonome: could not open monome device: Permission denied
failed to open /dev/ttyUSB0

[jeff@jbb-dell:~]$ sudo monomeserial
[sudo] password for jeff:
monomeserial version 1.4.2, yay!
initialized device m0000102 (monome 256) at /dev/ttyUSB0, which is 16x16 using proto
 mext
running with prefix /monome
^C

[jeff@jbb-dell:~]$
```

I can already use my USB printer from NixOS without using `sudo`, so I strongly suspect this is possible. How can I modify the package so that running it with `sudo` is unnecessary?

Comment: no you cant use your printer, the print daemon does. the user running the usb access needs to be part of the group with usb permissions

Comment: @camelccc sounds good! Do you know what that group is called? Does it always exist? I can see all groups on my system in the file `/etc/group`, but none of them has a name with any clear connection to USB devices.

Comment: if you ls -a your /dev/ you should get the group of your usb device  add this group to the groups that the user is a member of and it should work.

Comment: you will need to log out and back in for a group modification to take effect

Comment: How would I know what group to add myself to? I created a file with every group name (`egrep -oh "^[^:]*" group > groupnames`), and another with the name of everything in `/dev` (`ls -a1 /dev > devnames`)and computed their intersection (`sort groupnames devnames | uniq -d`) and I got seven files: 

`audio`,
`cdrom`,
`disk`,
`input`,
`kvm`,
`root`, and
`tty`. Is it one of those?

Comment: what is the group of /dev/ttyUSB0 (the device that you can't open) ?

Comment: Aha! Adding that group to `users.users.jeff.extraGroups` solved the problem. Thanks! (This whole time I thought I had to modify the *application* to have permission to access the device, when in fact I only had to make sure the *user* has permission.) Would you like to write up the solution, or shall I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely caused by the user that the application is running as not having permission to access the USB device. The clue is `failed to open /dev/ttyUSB0`
You may think that you have usb access because you can use printers and usb sticks, but these are accessed by daemons that do not run as your uid

To fix this, obtain the group of the USB device by running `ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0` (replace with the name of your USB if different) and add this group to the list of secondary groups for the user that needs to access the device. You will need to log out and in for this modification to take effect.

There are security implications of this, since any USB can now be written, but its certainly a lot better than running the program via root via sudo. Consider the use of `setgid` on the executible that performs the access if many users will need to run this, though this has other security issues.